# Minimum time to find maximum number with multiple CPUs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, max

For example, suppose there are 32 numbers (not sorted, range unknown) and 8 CPUs, each computes a single comparison per minute.

If there is just a single CPU, then there needs to be 31 comparisons.
But with 8 CPUs, we can compare 16 numbers per minute.

What is the minimum amount of time (in minutes) required to compute the maximum number?
(I worked it out to be around 6 minutes but I think it is possible to do in 5, not sure how the algorithm works.)

Comment: Can we assume that there is a central program that instantaneously decides what comparisons to delegate to the 8 CPUs after the previous comparison results are obtained?  Or do the 8 CPUs all have to finish their instruction sets entirely before we can aggregate and output the answer?

Comment: That is one slow CPU you've got there :)

Comment: @torquestomp The CPUs have to finish their comparison. Assume it's a naive (simple) system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1) 32 numbers -> compare 8 pairs using 8 CPUs -> 24 numbers
2) 24 numbers -> compare 8 pairs using 8 CPUs -> 16 numbers
3) 16 numbers -> compare 8 pairs using 8 CPUs -> 8 numbers
4) 8 numbers  -> compare 4 pairs using 4 CPUs -> 4 numbers
5) 4 numbers  -> compare all numbers with each other using 6 CPUs (tetrahedron)
```

Comment: Since you have 4 wasted CPU's at step 4, you can probably randomly pick additional values of different pairs to compare and, if these values turn out to be the maximum in their respective pairs, it's possible to already know the result without the 5th step.

Answer (score 2):

(Edited)
1st 4 steps are easy

1. compare 8 pairs (16 numbers) -> 8 winners1
2. compare 8 pairs (16 numbers) -> 8 winners2
3. compare 8 pairs (8-winner1 vs 8-winner2) -> 8 winners,
4. compare 4 pairs -> 4 winners

   Lets say 4 numbers are `a, b, c, d`
5. compare 6 pairs (a,b) (a,c) (a,d) (b,c) (b,d) (c,d) -> the Biggest number will win 3 times

Comment: Step four: `a=c=e=g=1; b=d=f=h=2`. There are four winners.

Comment: I assumed all numbers will be unique, but this 4 winner case is a special case where we will only have 2 winners for the step 5.

Comment: even with unique entries, you have `10,20,11,21,12,22,13,23` => four winners (`20,21,22,23`)

Comment: It seems correct. It kinda reminds me of [Egor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16594109/499214) ;-)

Comment: When I 1st read his answer I actually did not get it, so started to think of myself :p

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like an NCAA Bracket, where you let each core handle a game/minute.  Throw in the tetrahedron logic for the last 4, and you save yourself 1 minute.